# "you and your" vs "your and your"

Tags: grammar, pronouns, possessives, possessive-pronouns

At one point, **you** and your teammate's pokemons register a very low HP (1).

At one point, **your** and your teammate's pokemons register a very low HP (2).

Which of the two sentences is correct?

Comment: 1st one is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Sample Utterances

At one point, you and your teammate's pokemons register a very low HP (1). [OKAY]

At one point, your and your teammate's pokemons register a very low HP (2). [NOT okay; much too awkward]

At one point, your teammate's Pokemon's and yours register a very low HP (2). BETTER

It's best to state the thing first and place the pronoun yours [his, hers, theirs, ours] after that. It is much clearer.

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou  Ελα παιδακι μου  I don't want to make that public, do you understand? Yes, I know a little Greek. :)

Comment: @MariosAthanasiou You must be kidding.

Answer (score 1):

The second is correct. Consider removing some words, and see if it makes sense:

*At one point, your pokemons register a very low HP.

At one point, your teammate's pokemons register a very low HP.*

The first would have to be rewritten to be correct:

*At one point, your teammate's and your pokemons register a very low HP.*